# How can I disable an information that is stored in mongodB database to not show up in the frontend but it shouldn't be deleted from the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to disable users so that certain users cannot log in to my HRMS portal. I am using mongo dB database with Angular and Node js

So I've researched about disabling users and all the results come up as deleting the user.

```
var UserInfo = require('../models/userinfo');

exports.deleteUserinfo = function (req, res, next) {
  UserInfo.remove({ _id: req.params.userinfo_id }, function (err, userinfo) {
    res.json('Removed Successfully');
  });
}
```

The expected result is that I want to disable users and not delete the user. The above code deletes the user.

Answer (score 0):

So you can design a *soft delete* feature.
You simply have to add an information in your `user` schema that will store the status of your user.

Something like:

```
var UserInfo = new Schema({
  //...
  disabled: { type: boolean, default: false }
})
```

This way you have the possibility to disable a user by setting up `disabled` property to `true` and check this value at login to allow, or not, the connection to your application.

```
exports.deleteUserinfo = function (req, res, next) {
  UserInfo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.userinfo_id, { disabled: true }, function (err, userinfo) {
    res.json('Removed Successfully');
  });
}
```

And you can perform the opposite operation if you want to reallow the user to login.